# Set the z axis height in google javascript surfaceplot

Tags: javascript

Using google javascript surface-plot , i have made a 3d graph . 
But the z axis seems to be much higher even if the data is small.
Is there any way to set the height of z axis

Comment: Have you tried normalizing the data to [0, 1] before plotting?

Comment: Thanks Greg . But the problem with normalizing is ,you can't get the actual data by looking at the axis labels. Is there a way to specify labels separately?

Comment: No probs. If you're using the WebGL version then just set autoCalcZScale to false and specify the x, y and z label arrays. You can experiment here: http://jsfiddle.net/4N7jQ/1/  Have a look at the options object at line 81.

Comment: Thanks Greg .It really worked. By the way, is it possible to have multiple axis in surfaceplot?

Comment: Glad it worked. I'm afraid you can't add more axes.